# Life cycle called when backpress is pressed to navigate back to the previous activity?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

What activity state is called when another activity, in the same application, is launched, and then the backpress button is clicked to navigate back to it?

What lifecylce method is called during the proccess of going back to the previous activity?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`onPause()` is called in Activity **A** when it launches Activity **B**. After the *back* button is called in Activity **B**, `onResume()` is called in Activity **A**.

Answer (score 1):

> What lifecylce method is called during the proccess of going back to
>   the previous activity?

According to the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html): `onPause()`, `onStop()`, and possibly `onDestroy()`.  In addition to the lifecycle documentation, you might want to read the docs on [Tasks and Back Stack](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html).